# How to divide the composite into different spaces in SWT

Tags: java, layout, swt

I am create a log viewer in SWT and I ran across a problem where I need to display the mainText and detailedText. I wants the mainText to have only 25% or available space and detailText should have 75% available space.  So I went ahead and try to learn layout manager in swt [mention here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). Looks like SWT does not have any respective layout manger for me. I am currently using `FillLayout` which is simply diving the composite into equal space. Is there any way I can divide the space according to my convenience.

```
public class LogViewer{
 Text mainText;
 Text detailText;
 public void initialize(Composite parent){
  parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
  mainText = new Text( parent, SWT.WRAP | SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  detailText = new Text( parent, SWT.WRAP | SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  mainText.setVisible( true );
  detailText.setVisible( true );
  mainText.setText("This is the error message");
  detailText.setText("This text is mulitline error text message")
 }
}
```

This is how message is appearing

[image]

This is how I want

[image]

Could someone please help me and guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at using `org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm`. The `SashForm.setWeights` methods allows relative sizes to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sincerely like to thanks greg-449. His comment made it possible. He suggested me to use  [`org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FSashForm.html) and it works perfectly. Thanks SO again. Here is my updated code.

```
public class LogViewer{
 Text mainText;
 Text detailText;
 public void initialize(Composite parent){
  parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
  SashForm sashForm =new SashForm(parent, SWT.VERTICAL);
  mainText = new Text( sashForm , SWT.WRAP | SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  detailText = new Text( sashForm , SWT.WRAP | SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  mainText.setVisible( true );
  detailText.setVisible( true );
  sashForm.setWeights(new int[]{1,3});
  mainText.setText("This is the error message");
  detailText.setText("This text is mulitline error text message")
 }
}
```